# How to set a Paypal Sandbox test account address

Tags: paypal-sandbox

Trying to do my first tests of my new Paypal Standard Buttons with a test account.

After noticing the taxes were not being charged correctly I added Ontario taxes to my sandbox business account profile and bingo, the Ontario sales tax got charged. BUT I see nowhere in the TEST account profile that I used for the transaction where I could set its province of residence...

How do I change it to being Quebec for instance, so the Quebec sales tax gets charged?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok figured it out myself.

Basically you need to log into the sandbox as one of your test accounts and then change its address to anything you like. The same goes for details on credit cards.

1- So first logon to the developer site:
https://developer.paypal.com/developer

2- Go to Dashboard

3- Click on Accounts under Sandbox on the left (make sure you have set a password on the one you want to use below....)

4- Click on Enter Sandbox link in the middle of the right pane.

5- Click on the SECOND LOGOUT (NOT the one on the very top, that would log you out of Paypal altogether!) to logout your business sandbox account

6- Log back into the sandbox using a test client account

7- Play with its address all you like.

Changing an account address to the province of Quebec , then entering a transaction using that account charged the proper Quebec tax.

Cheers.

Comment: The "Enter Sandbox link" does not seem to exist any more but it seems that one can just sign in on https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ to the sandbox accounts.